# Modify JS from clientside

Tags: javascript

Just a newbie question: Is it possible to modify scripts written in JS from my browser Chrome and run it successfully? I keep getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function onClick
```

even when I only modified a single letter of an already existing function.

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change JavaScript from client side or for the fact any other type of file. You may well edit files for the purpose of debugging using chrome tools or Firefox firebug.

Comment: You can change JS if u use proper parameters, and provide code through text box for example, then after you change it you just need to trigger it, but remember after postback script will reload

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes, you can modify a script using the Dev Tools in Chrome and have the browser rerun the modified script. It's called LiveEdit

More info:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#liveedit